# Is my room suitable for electric underfloor heating?

Tags: heating

We are in the process of buying a new home and would like to have ceramic tiles on the ground floor. This is more resistant but can get very cold in winter, so we thought of having underfloor heating.

The builder is not really helpful when it comes to changes, so they won't install water underfloor heating as it requires too much work. But I can probably convince them to install the electric one or do it myself.

The room to be heated is about 25sq meters. Is it suitable for electric heating?

Is there anything else I should consider apart from the room size?